# How to build Jodit?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, webpack, jodit

I need a non-minified/readable version of Jodit (https://github.com/xdan/jodit/tree/3.2.55).
So I tried to build it but I'm a newbie with composer, node, npm, webpack, TypeScript, ...

Someone can help me to do this step by step ?

For the moment I have a docker contener with :

1. ubuntu:latest
2. nodejs (v8.10.0)
3. npm (3.5.2)

and a git clone of the repository of Jodit.

What is the next step ?
A "webpack" command ?
Which one ?

Comment: There's guidance in its repo (README.md).

Comment: Yes I know.
I should have explained that I tried this, and many other things, without success.

I will send details later.
But it does not seem easy on StackOverflow !

Comment: I give more information on this french forum: https://www.developpez.net/forums/d2016205/javascript/typescript/compiler-jodit/#post11195021

Answer (score 0):

To date, ubuntu:latest is version 18.04.
So this is not a recent version of nodejs and npm.

Based on ubuntu: 19.04, you can compile the project.